# In JavaScript, add to array if sending one at a time

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

Ultimately I need to display a list (if more than one) from an array.  I'm catching errors, and then displaying a list of the strings that had an error (trying to download).
These are strings coming from an Observable, sent one string at a time, so the array is always length of 1, and displays the last value sent.  How do I keep filling this array?
(Using Angular 9, no jQuery)

error.service...

```
 public errorDownloadingDoc$ = new Subject<any>();

  // getDocError gets called multiple times in one request, for each doc requested (to download), handles one doc at a time
  getDocError(doc): Observable<boolean> {
    return new Observable((observer: Observer<boolean>) => {
      this.dataService.getDoc(doc).subscribe((content) => {
        if (content) {
          observer.next(true);
          observer.complete();
        }
      }, (error) => {
        if (error) {
          const allErrorsArrary = [];
          allErrorsArrary.push(doc);
          console.log(allErrorsArrary);  // trying to collect all the errors into one array
          this.errorDownloadingDoc$.next(allErrorsArrary);  // sends to component
        }
      }
      );
    });
  }
```

component.ts...

```
ngOnInit() { 
 this.subscriptions.push(
      this.offlineZipDownloadService.errorDownloadingDoc$.subscribe(
        (allErrorsArrary) => {
          this.docNotDownloadedFromError = allErrorsArrary;
        }
       )
      );

}
```

html...

```
 <div *ngFor="let err of docNotDownloadedFromError">
    <P>Documents: {{ err }} </P>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so what you want is error.service to have an array that accumulates the errors?
try defining the array outside, right now you re-define it every time an error is sent..
Like this (assuming everything else works fine):

```
public errorDownloadingDoc$ = new Subject<any>();
const allErrorsArrary = [];

getDocError(doc): Observable<boolean> {
    return new Observable((observer: Observer<boolean>) => {
      this.dataService.getDoc(doc).subscribe((content) => {
        if (content) {
          observer.next(true);
          observer.complete();
        }
      }, (error) => {
        if (error) {
          allErrorsArrary.push(doc);
          console.log(allErrorsArrary);
          this.errorDownloadingDoc$.next(allErrorsArrary); 
        }
      }
      );
    });
  }
```